# Deserialized object from the database in java

Tags: java

object serializing method is here......

```
    public static void addNewFootBallClubToPremierLeague() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException, IOException{

    DatabaseConnection.getConnection();        
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
    FootBallClub.createFootBallClub();        
    oos.writeObject(FootBallClub.fbc);
    int hashCode=FootBallClub.getNewFootBallClubName().hashCode();
    byte[] footBallClubAsBytes = baos.toByteArray();
    PreparedStatement pstmt = DatabaseConnection.conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO PremierLeague VALUES(?,?)");
    ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(footBallClubAsBytes);
    pstmt.setInt(1, hashCode);
    pstmt.setBlob(2, bais);
    pstmt.executeUpdate();
    DatabaseConnection.conn.close();

}
```

Object Desirializing method is here.......

```
    public static void statisticsOfSelectedPremierLeagueFootBallClubs() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException, IOException{

    DatabaseConnection.getConnection();
    DatabaseConnection.st1=DatabaseConnection.conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = DatabaseConnection.st1.executeQuery("SELECT name FROM PremierLeague");
    FootBallClub fbc =null;
    while (rs.next()) {

        byte[] bArr = (byte[]) rs.getObject(1);
        ByteArrayInputStream baip = new ByteArrayInputStream(bArr);
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(baip);
        fbc =  (FootBallClub) ois.readObject();
        System.out.println(fbc);
      }         

    DatabaseConnection.st.close();
    rs.close();
    DatabaseConnection.conn.close();
}
```

When I execute 2nd method ,All the objects are null,but when I printed object input stream object in second method like this::::

`System.out.println(ois);`

this statement's out put is not null.

Why is it?

Answer (score 0):

`ois` is not null because constructors never return null. They either return the new instance of that class or they throw an exception.

`ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(baip);` This will create a new instance of `ObjectInputStream` and `ois` points to that instance. Your `ois.readObject()` may be null or it will throw an exception.

One more important thing is, Never ever store the serialized stream in database, because if you ever have change the class's structure like adding a method or a variable, the serialized objects may not deserialize properly.

Comment: `ois.readObject()` might return null, if `baip` is null. Are your writes are correct? `oos.writeObject(FootBallClub.fbc)` what is `fbc` here? You have serialized object stored in database. I was assuming you have null in database and you asking why `ois` is not null.

Comment: When I execute System.out.println(ois);
result is::::
          Connected to the database
java.io.ObjectInputStream@39ed3c8d
java.io.ObjectInputStream@71dac704
java.io.ObjectInputStream@123772c4
java.io.ObjectInputStream@2d363fb3

But When I execute this::::System.out.println(fbc);
result is::::::::
Connected to the database
null
null
null
null